# google play permission! What core functionalities in your app require SMS and Call Log permissions?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Previously declared permissions (2 permissions):

- `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`
- `android.permission.READ_SMS`

**Choose at least one core functionality before saving.**

```
Default SMS handler
Default Phone handler
Default Assistant handler
Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)
Enterprise SMS call archives
Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking
Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)
Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls
SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)
SMS based money management
Proxy calls
Services - Carrier
Services - OEM
Device Automation
Physical safety/emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)
Call-based OTP account verification
Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)
Write and Show Call History in Dialer
In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display
```

I removed the permission and released the new apk, and it worked fine, but while uploading on Google Play Store it asks for one core feature. But in my app I've already taking out the permissions. Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: Better to contact google play developer support team asap

Comment: @Sanchit did you found any answer ?

Comment: please share answer here so it can help others

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of investigation and experiment If found a solution which worked for me.

I removed all the SMS permissions from Manifest file and increment the app Version and submitted into Play store selecting any core feature.

Then again I generate one more apk and increment the app version and submitted into play store  Now this time Google didn't ask core feature selection.  and App is published

Comment: @Diptundu Das what about those application which have permission  !!

Comment: you request Google with declaration why your app needs this permission, then they give access to your app. read this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102